# How could I breakdown 1 row in excel to multiple rows for normalization?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Now I have an Excel table like this:

| Order | Customer | Purchased Items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | Apple10, Orange20, Banana30 |
| 2 | Mary | Strawberry25, Mango25, Watermelon10, Cherry20 |

The purchase items are saved as a string for every order and it is impossible to filter either the name of the item or the number of qty to do some calculations or grouping.

Is there a way to modify the table to be like this so I can work on the table?

| Order | Customer | Purchased Items | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | Apple | 10 |
| 1 | David | Orange | 20 |
| 1 | David | Banana | 30 |
| 2 | Mary | Strawberry | 25 |
| 2 | Mary | Mango | 25 |
| 2 | Mary | Watermelon | 10 |
| 2 | Mary | Cherry | 20 |

I tried some built-in functions of excel like Text to Columns but it is not working in the way I wanted. Is there any methods to transform the table in a easy way? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data. Edit your question with the real data.

Comment: Do you want to use power query split text by delimiter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Order", Int64.Type}, {"Customer", type text}, {"Purchased Items", type text}}),

//Split the "Items" column by comma into separate rows
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = 
        Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {
            {"Purchased Items", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
                                let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Purchased Items"),
    
//Remove the extra spaces
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Purchased Items", Text.Trim, type text}}),

//split column at transition from non-digit to digit
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = 
        Table.SplitColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Purchased Items", 
            Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), 
            {"Purchased Items", "QTY"}),

//set the data type of the QTY column
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{{"QTY", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: Especially on larger sets I think this is the better option.

Comment: Thanks! Using Power Query M code is very intuitive. I am putting it to my learning list now :)

Answer (score 3):

Using Office 365:

```
=LET(a,A2:C3,
REDUCE(HSTACK(A1:C1,"Qty"),SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
LAMBDA(x,y,
   LET(z,INDEX(a,y,{1,2}),
       s,SEQUENCE(26,,65),
VSTACK(x,
       IFERROR(
               HSTACK(z,
                      TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(a,y,3),,VSTACK(", ",SEQUENCE(10,,0)),1),
                      --TEXTSPLIT(
INDEX(a,y,3),,VSTACK(", ",CHAR(s),CHAR(s+32)),1)),
               z))))))
```

REDUCE uses the header values as a start value and adds the values of the first two columns of the nth (`y`) row of the range, starting from row 2 and a vertically textsplitted array of the 3rd column of the same row. First splitted by a numeric value from 0 to 9 or `", "` next splitted by any alphabets or `", "`.

Since the vertically splitted arrays aren't the same size as the single row of the nth row of the first two columns, the spilling array contains error values, which need to be filled up with this same value (`z`).

REDUCE iterates through the rows and stacks the individual calculation results, including the start value (headers including `Qty`

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured out using the GUI interface to split twice to achieve the results as you hinted (by delimiter by row -> non-digit to digit). Using formula approach is also interesting though :)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative using a `Excel Formulas` without using any `LAMBDA()` helper functions as well using one single input.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Order, INDEX(A2:C10,,1), _Customer, INDEX(A2:C10,,2), _PurchaseItems, INDEX(A2:C10,,3),
     _SplitByDelimiter, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&_PurchaseItems,", ",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(_PurchaseItems)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_PurchaseItems,",",))+1))),","),
     _CreateNColumnsOrder, TOCOL(IF(_SplitByDelimiter<>"",_Order),2),
     _CreateNColumnsCustomer, TOCOL(IF(_SplitByDelimiter<>"",_Customer),2),
     _ColumnsToRows, TOCOL(_SplitByDelimiter,2),
     _ExtractPurchaseItems, TEXTSPLIT(_ColumnsToRows,CHAR(SEQUENCE(10,,48)),,1),
     _ExtractQty, SUBSTITUTE(_ColumnsToRows,_ExtractPurchaseItems,)+0,
     _BodyExtracted, IFERROR(HSTACK(_CreateNColumnsOrder, _CreateNColumnsCustomer, _ExtractPurchaseItems, _ExtractQty),""),
     VSTACK({"Orders","Customer","Purchased Items","Qty"}, _BodyExtracted))
```

---

The above formula ignores where the `Purchased Items` & `Customer` is blank but does fills once the `Purchase Items` has a value. All the variables listed/defined in a way to understand what each of the following does, however, the best bet in transforming such a data is using `Power Query` which makes it relatively easy and simpler.

---

Comment: Great stuff. Hate the long variable names though.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir even i am not fond of, but it usually helps one to identify what each of the formulas does.

Comment: Thanks. Your formulas are clear to read with defined variable.

Answer (score 2):

### Transform Data: 'Unpivot' Delimited Data (Excel Formula)

```
=LET(data,A2:C11,left_cols,{1;2},split_col,3,dlm,", ",
    ld,CHOOSECOLS(data,left_cols),
    sd,CHOOSECOLS(data,split_col),
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        s,TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(sd,r,1),,dlm),
        i,IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(s,SEQUENCE(10,,0)),IFERROR(s,"")),
        p,IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(s,LEN(s)-LEN(i))),IF(i="","",0)),
    VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(IF(SEQUENCE(IFERROR(ROWS(s),1)),
        CHOOSEROWS(IF(ld="","",ld),r)),i,p))))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your formula, it is a very nice approach to solve the problem :)